# Sending http patch request with list of maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, http-patch, flutter-http

I have a class StyleItem, which looks like following:

```
class StyleItem {
  String id;
  double dx;
  double dy;
  double scale;
  double rotation;

  StyleItem({this.id, this.dx, this.dy, this.scale, this.rotation});

  Map toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'dx': dx,
      'dy': dy,
      'scale': scale,
      'rotation': rotation,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'id: $id, dx: $dx, dy: $dy, scale: $scale';
  }
}
```

Then I have a patch request, whose body should look like

```
{
    "occasion": "[Date, Outing, Ethnic]",
    "weather": "[Rainy, Sunny]",
    "style_items": [
        {"id": "5faacbb3ac0d1900177e94bd", "dx": "0.35462962962962963", "dy": "0.7447916666666667", "scale": "0.4", "rotation": "0.0"}
    ]
}
```

The field `style_items` is supposed to have array of such map of object of class `StyleItem`.
I have tried encoding these object with `jsonEncode`, but then backend could not read `id`.

And through Postman, I have made sure backend is working properly.

For making patch request i am using, `http` package.
Following code is used

```
// This is the complete function
// First I upload a picture for which I get a 'imgUrl'
// With this and other information, I make the patch request
// Field 'style_items' is the one which causes problem.
Future<bool> addNewLook(var image, Map<String, String> details, List<StyleItem> styleItems) async {
    try {
      Uri savingImgUrl = Uri.http(BASE_URL, CHAT_IMAGE_URL);
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', savingImgUrl);
      request.files
          .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', image.path));
      request.headers.addAll({'token': token});
      var res = await request.send();
      var response = await http.Response.fromStream(res);
      var resBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      String imgUrl = resBody['url'];
      print("ImgUrl: "+imgUrl);

      // Required section, where I face the issue.
      Uri savingDataUrl = Uri.http(BASE_URL, CREATE_LOOK+"/$_id");
      var body = {
        'image': imgUrl,
        'occasion': details['occasion'],
        'weather': details['weather'],
        // This field has the problem
        'style_items': jsonEncode(styleItems.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList())
      };
      response = await http.patch(savingDataUrl, headers: {
        'token': token
      }, body: body);
      if(response.statusCode!=200) {print("ErrorAddingNewLook! Response: "+response.body); return false;}
      print(response.body);
      resBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      Look look = Look();
      look.fromJson(resBody['data']);
      _request.preMadeLooks.add(look);
      print("SavingLooks: Response: "+resBody.toString());
      return true;
    } catch(err) {
      print("ErrorAddingNewLook! Error: "+err.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Also I have tried to encode to Json for the field `style_items` in different ways

```
// Try1
styleItems.map((e) => jsonEncode(e.toJson())).toList()
// Try2
styleItems.map((e) => jsonEncode(e.toJson())).toList().toString()
// Try3
jsonEncode(styleItems.map((e) => jsonEncode(e.toJson())).toList())
```

Comment: add the api call code too

Comment: @AkshitOstwal Thank You for looking into the problem.. I have updated the question, I have been stuck on this for so long.. I hope to find a solution soon.Thank you.. sir!

Comment: it's easier to debug, if you able to show what your style_items are after jsonEncode()

Comment: @xion This is the style_items after jsonEncode()[{"id":"5fc8b108e0602300172cf81e","dx":0.1685185185185185,"dy":0.1963541666666667,"scale":0.2,"rotation":0.0},{"id":"5fc78cafdb233c0017961dd4","dx":0.17870370370370375,"dy":0.49218750000000006,"scale":0.2,"rotation":0.0}]

Comment: based on what you show in your question, and the style_items in comment, the dx,dy columns is diff type, 1 is string, and another is integer, should you be concern with that?

Comment: Thank you for taking this up, actually we managed this, by backend guy making changes, he needed to parse the string I sent to json object, and then it was done.